# Copy a flat buffer for later processing

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, flatbuffers

I have a service receiving a stream of flatbuffers messages, for most the processing is inline, but form a few messages I need to save them for later processing:

```
char buf[] = recv(...);
const MyMessage* msg = GetSizePrefixedMyMessage(buf);
process(msg);
MyMessage *saved = Copy(msg) ??? how can I copy it?
```

Because each fields of flatbuffers message is a member function instead of real data, so I cannot just memcpy, right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `GetSizePrefixedMyMessage()` written by you? If yes, then I would recommend use of `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `memcpy` the accessor pointer `msg`, but you can simply `memcpy` the original `buf`.

Comment: sorry, i don't hold the original buf. the example code is only for demonstration.

Comment: Well, that's the only way you can copy. If you don't have access to the buffer, no copy for you.

Answer (score -2):

> MyMessage *saved = Copy(msg) ??? how can I copy it?

You should be able to copy it with a copy constructor, given that it's defined:

```
MyMessage saved(*msg); // If you like to have it on the stack, 
    // but will get destroyed as soon as you leave the scope. 
    // Preferred way unless MyMessage is big
MyMessage* saved= new MyMessage(*msg); // Could be auto instead of MyMessage*. 
    // We don't do this anymore on modern C++, you need a call to delete
auto saved= std::make_unique<MyMessage>(*msg); // This gets deleted automatically
    // falling out of scope
```

If you don't have a copy constructor but an assignment operator:

```
MyMessage saved; 
saved= *msg; // Copy
MyMessage* saved= new MyMessage();
*saved= *msg; // Copy
auto saved= std::make_unique<MyMessage>();
*saved= *msg; // Copy
```

Given that those two fail, if MyMessage is a simple struct (without pointers, no virtuals), you *could* do:

```
MyMessage saved;
memcpy(&saved, msg, sizeof(MyMessage));
MyMessage* saved= new MyMessage();
memcpy(saved, msg, sizeof(MyMessage));
auto saved= std::make_unique<MyMessage>();
memcpy(saved.get(), msg, sizeof(MyMessage));
```

Comment: sorry but the message is a flatbuffers, so none of these methods are available.

Comment: `memcpy` is a C library function. You just need to `#include <cstring>` or `#include <string.h>`

Comment: Also, `msg` is of class `MyMessage`, which is your class